# Ionic 3 : Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am calling an alert on my Page.

```
addError(title,message){
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        'title': title,
        'subTitle': message,
        'buttons': ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

Html Code with content including button and textbox.

```
<ion-content padding>

 <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Secret</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="secret"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <div padding>
    <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="add();" block>Add New</button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

The Entire .ts code is given below with class definition

```
class HomePage {
  name:string;
  secret:string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public alertCtrl: AlertController,public strorage:StorageServiceProvider) {

  }
  addError(title,message){
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        'title': title,
        'subTitle': message,
        'buttons': [{
                text: "Cancel", handler: () => {
                  alert.dismiss(); 
                  return false;
                }
              }]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
  add(){
    if(this.name && this.secret){
        this.strorage.addNew({'name':this.name,'secret':this.secret});
    }
    else{
        this.addError("Error","Please enter Secret name and Secret");
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error while I am calling the addError again.

**Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found**

Comment: Where did you call it? `code` of that use?

Comment: @Sampath on button click

Comment: You need to show the `html` code too.

Comment: please specify ts file also.

Comment: @Dr.Geek added ts file code as well

Comment: alert part  works well. Please run the below code `ionic info`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not coming from `addError` function and `alertController`.

The problem may occurs because of local storage usage `this.strorage.addNew({'name':this.name,'secret':this.secret});`

This localStorage usage must be as like

```
this.storage.addNew( key, value )  
this.storage.addNew( 'error', {'name':this.name,'secret':this.secret} )
```

In your code there is no key !..

Comment: If u use official ionic local storage this usage will be as `this.storage.set(key, value)`

Comment: strorage:StorageServiceProvider is my custom service and addNew accept a type any.

Comment: I can say that your alert works well because I tried....This problem is not related about alert component... please run `ionic info` and send add the details to your question